# How to select a value from a comma delimited string?

Tags: vb.net, csv, split

I have a string that contains comma delimited text.  The comma delimited text comes from an excel .csv file so there are hundreds of rows of data that are seven columns wide.  An example of a row from this file is:

2012-10-01,759.05,765,756.21,761.78,3168000,761.78

I want to search through the hundreds of rows by the date in the first column.  Once I find the correct row I want to extract the number in the first position of the comma delimited string so in this case I want to extract the number 759.05 and assign it to variable "Open".

My code so far is:

```
strURL = "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" & tickerValue
strBuffer = RequestWebData(strURL)

Dim Year As String = 2012
Dim Quarter As String = Q4
If Quarter = "Q4" Then
    Dim Open As Integer =
End If
```

Once I can narrow it down to the right row I think something like row.Split(",")(1).Trim) might work.

I've done quite a bit of research but I can't solve this on my own.  Any suggestions!?!

***ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:***

```
Private Function RequestWebData(ByVal pstrURL As String) As String
    Dim objWReq As WebRequest
    Dim objWResp As WebResponse
    Dim strBuffer As String
    'Contact the website
    objWReq = HttpWebRequest.Create(pstrURL)
    objWResp = objWReq.GetResponse()
    'Read the answer from the Web site and store it into a stream
    Dim objSR As StreamReader
    objSR = New StreamReader(objWResp.GetResponseStream)
    strBuffer = objSR.ReadToEnd
    objSR.Close()

    objWResp.Close()

    Return strBuffer
End Function
```

***MORE ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:***

A more complete picture of my code

```
Dim tickerArray() As String = {"GOOG", "V", "AAPL", "BBBY", "AMZN"}

For Each tickerValue In Form1.tickerArray

        Dim strURL As String
        Dim strBuffer As String
        'Creates the request URL for Yahoo
        strURL = "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" & tickerValue

        strBuffer = RequestWebData(strURL)

        'Create Array
        Dim lines As Array = strBuffer.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)

        'Add Rows to DataTable
        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr("Ticker") = tickerValue
        For Each columnQuarter As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            Dim s As String = columnQuarter.ColumnName
            If s.Contains("-") Then
                Dim words As String() = s.Split("-")
                Dim Year As String = words(0)
                Dim Quarter As String = words(1)
                Dim MyValue As String
                Dim Open As Integer
                If Quarter = "Q1" Then MyValue = Year & "-01-01"
                If Quarter = "Q2" Then MyValue = Year & "-04-01"
                If Quarter = "Q3" Then MyValue = Year & "-07-01"
                If Quarter = "Q4" Then MyValue = Year & "-10-01"
                For Each line In lines
                    Debug.WriteLine(line)
                    If line.Split(",")(0).Trim = MyValue Then Open = line.Split(",")(1).Trim
                    dr(columnQuarter) = Open
                Next
            End If

        Next
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next
```

Right now in the `For Each line in lines` loop, `Debug.WriteLine(line)` outputs 2,131 lines:

From

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2013-02-05,761.13,771.11,759.47,765.74,1870700,765.74
2013-02-04,767.69,770.47,758.27,759.02,3040500,759.02
2013-02-01,758.20,776.60,758.10,775.60,3746100,775.60
```

All the way to...

```
2004-08-19,100.00,104.06,95.96,100.34,22351900,100.34
```

But, what I expect is for `Debug.WriteLine(line)` to output one line at a time in the `For Each line in lines` loop.  So I would expect the first output to be `Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close` and the next output to be `2013-02-05,761.13,771.11,759.47,765.74,1870700,765.74`.  I expect this to happen 2,131 times until the last output is `2004-08-19,100.00,104.06,95.96,100.34,22351900,100.34`

Comment: I actually changed those values for the post so that I could post an abbreviated version of my code.  Those values are actually split from a string earlier in the code.  They look like Dim Year As     String = words(0)
    Dim Quarter As String = words(1)

Comment: @TimSchmelter What do you mean by "Change your OPTION STRICT to "ON" as soon as possible!"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could loop through the lines and call `String.Split` to parse the columns in each line, for instance:

```
Dim lines() As String = strBuffer.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
For Each line As String In lines
    Dim columns() As String = line.Split(","c)
    Dim Year As String = columns(0)
    Dim Quarter As String = columns(1)
Next
```

However, sometimes CSV isn't that simple.  For instance, a cell in a spreadsheet could contain a comma character, in which case it would be represented in CSV like this:

```
example cell 1,"example, with comma",example cell 3
```

To make sure you're properly handling all possibilities, I'd recommend using the [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class.  For instance:

```
Using parser As New TextFieldParser(New StringReader(strBuffer))
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited
    parser.SetDelimiters(",")
    While Not parser.EndOfData
        Try
            Dim columns As String() = parser.ReadFields()
            Dim Year As String = columns(0)
            Dim Quarter As String = columns(1)
        Catch ex As MalformedLineException
            ' Handle the invalid formatting error
        End Try 
    End While 
End Using
```

Comment: When I use this method and then debug using Debug.WriteLine(lines) it tells me that "lines" returns "System.String[]" I expected to see the array.

Comment: `String[]` is an array of strings.  That's what the `[]` means.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I just realized that I misunderstood your comment.  If you want to output the array to the debug window, you'd need to make a for loop that outputs each line separately.  The `ToString` method for arrays has not been overridden to support outputting all of the items.  Instead, it just uses the base `Object.String` method which simply outputs the type name of the object.

Comment: I'm trying   
                        For Each line In lines
                        Debug.WriteLine(line) 
                        Next
And I get the entire string that is hundreds of lines long.  I expected to see just one string.  Like this for example 2013-02-01,758.20,776.60,758.10,775.60,3746100,775.60

Comment: Now you've lost me.  If you want to display the original un-split string, you could just output `strBuffer`.  If you split the array into many items, and then you output each item on a separate line, of course it will be many lines of output.  Am I missing or not understanding something?

Comment: I want to split the array into many items and then I want to output each item of the array one at a time.  So that I can check the first value of each item.

Comment: Define "one at a time".  Give me an example of how it is outputting vs. how you want it to output it.  It would probably be better if you did so as an update to your question, so I can see the formatting, rather than doing it in a comment where the formatting is more limited.

Comment: First of all thank you working with me.  I really appreciate it!  Please see my MORE ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: edit to my original post.  I think my problem is either the way I am loading the array or how I am looping through it.  I hope this portrays a clearer picture and clears up any confusion.  I feel like I am really close to where I want to be.  Thanks again!

Comment: I don't see a difference between your example of what is happening vs. what you expect to happen.  You said that right now it "outputs 2,131 lines", and you show what they are, but then you said that you expect it to, instead, output 2,131 lines and you give the exact same examples.  Please clarify.

Comment: My current program gives me the information that I want but it does not give it to me in the format that I want.  Right now it gives me all 2,131 lines at once.  I want it to give me each line one at a time.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "one at a time".  You mean you want it to pause between each line, or something?

Comment: Right now I have a breakpoint at the `Next` in the `For Each line In lines` loop.  That is how I know it gives me all 2,131 lines at once.  Before I let my program loop trough every line of the array `lines()`I stop it.  So I should only see the first line in debug at this point instead of all 2,131.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to check the first value of each line against a figure.  If the value of a line matches my figure I want to use the information in that line.  So I need each line separately so that I can check the first value of each line.

Comment: Ah.  You mean the String.Split is only returning one item?  In that case, the most likely culpit is that the new line character(s) used in the CSV file is not the same as `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: Yes, Awesome!  I am sorry it is hard for me to get my point across. I am new to this and not very well versed in it.  This sounds like my problem.  Any idea what I might use instead of `Environment.NewLine`?

Comment: Or any way to tell what the new line character(s) used in the my CSV file are?

Comment: You can see the hex code of the characters using any binary text editor.  It's most likely either `ControlChars.Cr` or `ControlChars.Lf`.  Again, this wouldn't be a problem, though, if you were using the `TextFieldParser` class.  Alternatively, you could use a `StringReader` object and call it's `ReadLine` method in a loop.  The `StringReader.ReadLine` method supports all the standard new line characters.

Comment: Great I will work with this and see if I can get it to work.  Thanks!

Comment: I get an error at this line that you recommended in a comment above.  `Dim sReader As New StreamReader(strBuffer)`.  The error is "ArgumentException was unhandled.  Illegal characters in path."  Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean where I suggested that you could use the `StringReader` class?  The `StringReader` is different than the `StreamReader`.

Comment: That is what I meant.  Sorry I didn't see the difference.  I believe my problem has been solved!  Just a little more tweaking required.  Thanks so much.  You've been a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

I would break it up into a `List(of string())` - Each row being a new entry in the list.

Then loop through the list and look at Value(0). 
`If Value(0) = MyValue, then Open = Value(1)`

Comment: That sounds good!  What goes into breaking it up into a List(of string())?

Comment: Where are you reading the data in?? if you're reading it in line-by-line then just, with each new line, load it into the list with the `MyList.Add` method. If you already have it as one long string with, say `VBCrLf` characters separating each line then just split it on that character and use the `.ToList` method

Comment: ... If you show where / how you read in the data, we'd be able to help more.

Comment: I edited my original post to show where / how I read in the data.

Comment: I'm very close to figuring this out I just need to know how to load each line of the file into an array.  I understand the rest of the logic.  I just need help separating the rows now!

Comment: I think I would rather change over to reading the data in line-by-line in an array.  Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: As in my answer, you can use `strBuffer.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)` to get an array of lines, or you can create a `New StringReader(strBuffer)` and then keep calling `StringReader.ReadLine` in a loop.

Comment: @StevenDoggart If I use strBuffer.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None) Where is the array of lines.  What is its name? Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: @nordeen1 I updated my answer to show how to create a variable to hold the array that is returned by that method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.Split` and this linq query:

```
Dim Year As Int32 = 2012
Dim Month As Int32 = 10
Dim searchMonth = New Date(Year, Month, 1)
Dim lines = strBuffer.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
Dim dt As Date
Dim open As Double
Dim opens = From line In lines
    Let tokens = line.Split({","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Where Date.TryParse(tokens(0), dt) AndAlso dt.Date = searchMonth AndAlso Double.TryParse(tokens(1), open)
If opens.Any() Then
    open = Double.Parse(opens.First().tokens(1))
End If
```